# Copying and moving message in another channel

Tags: discord.js

My `suggestion Script` worked totally fine for the last couple of months, but it stopped working a few days ago. I noticed that my `.send` function was underlined, and it said this:

```js
Property 'send' does not exist on type 'GuildChannel | ThreadChannel'.
Property 'send' does not exist on type 'GuildChannel'
```

I'm btw. not sure if that's the problem with the script or if they changed anything I didn't notice, and I'm getting no errors. The Script basically just don't work.

My suggestion script:

```js
        case "suggestion":
 
            var str = message.content.slice(" .suggestion".length);
            const suggestionembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setThumbnail('png')
                .setTitle("Suggestion")
                .setColor('#151515')
                .addFields(
                    { name: "Person, that suggested somenthing:", value: `<@!${message.author.id}>` },
                    { name: 'Suggestion:', value: `${str}` },
                    { name: 'Channel:', value: `${message.channel}` },
                )
                .setTimestamp()

 
            await message.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === 'suggestion')
                .send({ embeds: [suggestionembed] })
                .then(embedMessage => {
                    embedMessage.react("✅")
                    embedMessage.react("❌")
                });
            message.delete();
 
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ignore that if you are *sure* that it's a text channel. That is only there because it can be a `VoiceChannel`. You won't have autocomplete in Visual Studio Code but it will still work as intended. If you are using TypeScript, you could use `as` to tell TypeScript it's a `TextChannel`

Comment: Do you see any error in my code it suddenly stopped working tho and i don't know why

Comment: What do you mean *stopped working*? Any errors? Does it just end the node.js process?

Comment: With stopped working i mean. I don't get any errors, the bot isn't crashing or anything. He just doesn't react to the command anymore